# Is it risky to send a copy of my Passport to someone I only know online?

Tags: scams, jordan, fraud

A few months ago, I met a man online, who lives in Jordan. He has asked me to fly over there from the US to marry him. He will pay for my flight and other accommodation costs, to which I have agreed.

He asked me to send him a scanned copy of my passport, which now makes me hesitant. I want to know if anyone has been in this/similar situation before on Travel Stack Exchange?

Should I send him my passport details? What could someone do with a copy of my scanned passport?

Comment: How do you know it's _not_ a scam? I wouldn't disclose my passport details with anyone I met online. They may threaten to blackmail you once you hand in your passport details. Simply put - don't share your personal documents with anyone you meet online.

Comment: You're certainly not wrong to be hesitant, but to be blunt, I'd be far more concerned about marrying a man in a foreign country you've never met and are apparently concerned about. You feel uneasy about trusting someone with a copy of your passport, yet trust him with marriage?

Comment: The other two comments give you the warnings already. **Don't. Do. This.** https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57799/passport-copy-is-being-used-to-defraud-others-what-can-i-do. Still, if you insist: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170004/which-is-a-safe-way-to-transfer-a-copy-of-a-sensitive-document

Comment: it sounds like you have created 2 accounts. Please see here on how to be able to merge them: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. I was actually kinda worried about your situation!

Comment: @glglgl: Perhaps in your culture. Not everywhere.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit true :p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you name one country where it is acceptable to marry a person who lives in a foreign country and have never met you or your family in person?

Comment: @VarunAgw Most Muslim countries (save for the "or your family" part, as a Muslim marriage is a contract between the groom and the bride's *wali* - male guardian)

Answer (score 66):

**Do NOT continue speaking to this man, for your own safety!**

It's clear that you feel lonely and desperate for intimate companionship, and that's who these people target.

This man may either keep you in Jordan as a sex slave, use your identity for (further) criminal activities, force you to aid him in getting to the US illegally, or anything else. We don't know this man's exact intentions, but anyone saying they'll marry you after a few months of online contact along with requesting your passport information **invariably** is up to no good, period.

Think about whether you've disclosed anything sensitive about yourself in any way. If so, report this to the police. Otherwise, simply block him on all channels without a word.

Comment: This was my thought exactly. Relationship conversations are one thing. But asking for a copy of your passport screamed that something was wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

Sending personal info to anyone you don't know is always risky.

This seems very suspicious, and, in my opinion, you should stop talking to this person right now!

Some countries give absurd control to men over their wives. Not sure about Jordan, but might be worth to take a look at it.

Comment: Jordan isn't as primitive as Saudi or Iran, but still not a good place to get stuck in.

Comment: @Coke While I agree that Jordan is a not a bad place, the OP only mentioned that this man *lived* in Jordan.  Nothing was given about his nationality or cultural identity. So who knows what she would be walking into (assuming that he actually exists in the first place)

Answer (score 4):

That'd be a bad idea. Who knows what he'll do with the passport info alone. May be he'll start using the info on the passport to create some duplicate ones. May not be exactly that, may be he'll use your info for illegal activities.

People do this kind of stuff!

Forget about flying there, avoid any contact or sharing of personal details with this person.